# Reading an XML Feed into XElement

Tags: c#, xml, bing-maps, xelement, xmlstreamreader

I have an Xml Stream that I'd like to read into an `XElement`. I've seen samples that use `XmlTextReader` but I need it in an `XElement`.

The code that I have so far:

```
string url = 
 String.Format( "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/{0}?o=xml&key={1}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode( AddressQuery ), mapkey );

HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;  

XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader( url );
```

I'm just not sure how to get the reader into an XElement. Perhaps I'm going about it the wrong way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

with linq to xml you can simply do this

```
var xml = XElement.Load(uri);
```

Answer (score 4):

You've only created an instance of `WebRequest` - this doesn't actually ask the server to download the contents of the URL. Calling `WebRequest.GetResponse()` should download the contents of the URL from the server. The [MSDN page for WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) has an example of downloading the contents of a URL.

Once you have the response, you can call [XDocument.Load()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838349.aspx) and pass it the response stream (by calling `GetResponseStream()` from the response object). The `XDocument` class has methods to retrieve an `XElement` in the XML document.